# Split just the Issuer and Notafter

Tags: powershell

When I run `Get-ChildItem | Format-List -property Notafter, issuer | Out-String` I get the following returned:

```
NotAfter : 17/11/2036 13:36:15 
Issuer   : CN=NAMECERTIFICATE1

NotAfter : 17/11/2017 17:10:05 
Issuer   : CN=NAMECERTIFICATE1
```

But I want the dates and the Issuer of all certificates. How to do that?

I've tred `Get-ChildItem | Format-List -property Notafter, issuer | Out-String | %{$_.split(':')[1]}`

But this returns just the 1º date. I want to get the return:

```
17/11/2036
CN=NAMECERTIFICATE1

17/11/2017
CN=NAME CERTIFICATE2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't process the text, process the object:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {"{0:d}`n{1}" -f $_.notafter,$_.issuer}
```

the Powershell pipeline, unlike the pipe in other shells, doesn't pass text around, it passes actual manipulable objects. The best way to manage things in Powershell is "filter left, format right" - in other words, cut down what you're getting as early as possible, and put it into 'printable' format at the last possible minute. That way, you're managing the minimum amount of information with the maximum amount of flexibility.